# Spring Security SAML Plugin - defaultAlias

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

In the earlier version of the RC2 I was able to format my ACS url to:

```
/saml/SSO/alias/defaultAlias
```

This has been taken out in the release version.  What do I set the ACS url on my IDP server to hit the only or default provider on the SP side?

Answer (score 1):

The default URL is now simply `/saml/SSO`.

The alias feature is still available and supported - you can set it on MetadataGeneratorFilter's bean MetadataGenerator - ExtendedMetadata - property alias.

You can find an overview of changes between RC2 and FINAL [in the manual chapter 'Important code changes'](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#section-whats-new-code-changes), including guidelines on achieving backwards compatibility.